# How do I install an older version of ubuntu on raspberry pi 4?

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu, raspberry-pi-imager

I need to install an older version of Ubuntu (20.04) desktop version for compatibility reasons. The Raspberry Pi imager v1.6.2 on windows only shows Ubuntu desktop 21.10 as available.

I tried to download an older version of the imager, but that also only shows 21.10.

[image: Screenshot showing only 21.10]

Answer (score 1):

You can install ANY image.

The *Raspberry Pi imager* (any version) will only offer to DOWNLOAD the latest, but can be used to install any you have. There is a "custom" option.

I use it to restore my backups.

Comment: Yes, but how could I get the image for ubuntu 20.04? It isn't the typical ISO image, but needs to be a .img file for the Pi

Comment: @betelgeuse if you don't already have an image you will have to search on a Ubuntu site. Raspberry Pi OS has archives of its images but AFAIK only links to 3rd party images. I don't use Ubuntu because it is a resource hog and won't run on any of my Pi.

Answer (score 0):

You can find older release here https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/20.04/. Look for "raspi.img.xz"